# Define specific time points for cumulative incidence curves using "cuminc" function in R

Tags: r, curve, survival-analysis

I am a PhD student beginner in R and I have some issue to define specific time point in the cumulative incidence function obtained using the `cuminc()` function in R.

Here is a simulated dataset corresponding to my dataset :

```
# Set the sample size
n<- 8076
# CReate a variable for follow-up time
time<- c(rep(180,6533),sample(1:179,n-6533,replace = TRUE))
# Create a variable for status
status<-ifelse(time==180,0,1) # O= alive/censored
                          # 1 = death
# Create age
age<-sample(18:90,n,replace = TRUE)
# Create gender
sex<-sample(c("male","female"),n,replace = TRUE)
# Combine
df<-data.frame(time,status,age,sex) `
```

And here are my code to compute the cumulative incidence function and to plot the cumulative incidence function curves:

```
`# Cumulative incidence function
fit<-cuminc(df$time,df$status,df$sex)
print(fit)
# Plot the cumulative incidence curves
plot(fit,xlab = "Days",ylab = "Cumulative incidence",ylim=c(0,0.4))`
```

The time points obtained are 0, 50,100, 150 but I would like to have time points at 0, 30,90, and 180 days (both on the graph and on the output provided by print(fit)). As far as I understand, the argument 'timepoint' in "Cuminc" needs to be used to define time points but I do not understand how to use this argument correctly.

Many thanks in advance for you help :)

I tried to define a vector such as : times<-c(0,30,90,180) and I tried to add this vector in the "cuminc" code. I also try to directly modify the x-axis in the graph by using xlim=c(0,30,90,180) but I received an error message while for y-lim, it works correctly. I also try to use the timepoints argument in the cuminc function : timepoint(c(0,30,90,180)) but it didn't work..

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. You just need to use the `timepoints()` function from the same package and specify your desired timepoints :

```
timepoints(fit, c(0,30,90,180))
$est
         0         30         90       180
female 1 0 0.02985075 0.09676617 0.1878109
male 1   0 0.03402367 0.10108481 0.1942801

$var
         0           30           90          180
female 1 0 7.205719e-06 2.174761e-05 3.795530e-05
male 1   0 8.105104e-06 2.240886e-05 3.860418e-05
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer :) Do you know how to have the p-value when using the timepoint argument? And how to make the plot with the x-axis defined according to the same values? I tried to define timepoint(fit,c(30,90,180)) as fit1 and then plot(fit1) but it doesn't work ... thanks again :) !

Comment: To my knowledge there is no timepoint argument in the `cuminc()` function. If you want to have access to specific values you need the additional function `timepoints()`. The p-value is provided in the `fit` results. If you want to change the x-axis, you could use `plot(fit,xlab = "Days",ylab = "Cumulative incidence",ylim=c(0,0.4),xaxt='n') ; axis(side = 1, at=c(30,90,180))`